# Return type IResult<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, return-value, return-type

I try solve this problem in WPF app with MVVM design. 
I need return on database access more "data":

- result messages
- return value
- and if was database successful

So I create interface for return type, here is it:

```
public interface IResult<T> 
{
    bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    string ResultMessage { get; set; }
    T ReturnValue { get; set; } 
}
```

This interface implements some class:

```
public class DbResult: IResult<IList<Archive>>
{
    public bool IsSuccess{ get; set;}
    public string ResultMessage{ get; set;}
    public IList<Archive> ReturnValue { get; set; }

}
```

Method in class on databases access have return type `IResult<Archive>`, Archive is class generated with LINQ TO SQL.:

```
public interface IArchiveDbManager
{
    IResult<Archive> LoadConversationTo(string nick, DateTime toDt);
}

[Export(typeof(IArchiveDbManager))]
public partial class ArchiveDbManager : IArchiveDbManager
{
    public IResult<Archive> LoadConversationTo(string nick, DateTime toDt)
    {
        var result = new DbResult();

        try
        {
            var query = from m in _dc.Archive
                        where m.Nick == nick
                        where m.Time <= toDt
                        orderby m.Time
                        select m;

            result.ReturnValue = query.ToList();

            if (query.Count() == 0)
            {
                result.ResultMessage = "For the specified search criteria found no record in the database.";
                result.IsSuccess = false;
            }
            else
            {
                result.ResultMessage =
                    string.Format("For the specified search criteria found {0} record in the database.", query.Count());
                result.IsSuccess = true;
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            throw exception;
        }
    }

}
```

Class ArchiveDbManager is inject with MEF in view model class.

I have some question:

1. What is correct solution for this
   problem in MVVM? Scenario is view
   model create through
   ArchiveDbManager access to the
   database, for example if database
   table is empty, ArchiveDbManager
   class return message "Archive is
   empty" and view model show this
   message in view to the user.
2. It is right to create a report of
   the search results in a database in 
   "ArchiveDbManager class (it is a
   class on database access)"
3. What do you think about this
       solution?

Comment: Why the setters? Wouldn't an immutable `IResult<T>` be better?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: You don't really need the interface or class.

You only need to ask for the result, and the method should throw an exception with the error message is something goes wrong.

This kind of success result messages: `result.ResultMessage = "For the specified search criteria found no record in the database.";` do not belong to business logic or the data layer. The UI layer should be responsible for showing the messages to the user.